# Getting client original ip address with azure aks

Tags: nginx, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm currently working on copying AWS EKS cluster to Azure AKS.
In our EKS we use external Nginx with proxy protocol to identify the client real IP and check if it is whitelisted in our Nginx.
In AWS to do so we added to the Kubernetes service annotation `aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol` to support Nginx `proxy_protocol` directive.

Now the day has come and we want to run our cluster also on Azure AKS and I'm trying to do the same mechanism.
I saw that AKS Load Balancer hashes the IPs so I removed the `proxy_protocol` directive from my Nginx conf, I tried several things, I understand that Azure Load Balancer is not used as a proxy but I did read here:
[AKS Load Balancer Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard)
I tried whitelisting IPs at the level of the Kubernetes service using the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` api instead on the Nginx level.

But I think that the Load Balancer sends the IP to the cluster already hashed (is it the right term?) and the cluster seem to ignore the ips under `loadBalancerSourceRanges` and pass them through.

I'm stuck now trying to understand where I lack the knowledge, I tried to handle it from both ends (load balancer and kubernetes service) and they both seem not to cooperate with me.
Given my failures, what is the "right" way of passing the client real IP address to my AKS cluster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic#create-an-ingress-controller

> If you would like to enable client source IP preservation for requests
> to containers in your cluster, add `--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local` to the Helm install
> command. The client source IP is stored in the request header under
> `X-Forwarded-For`. When using an ingress controller with client source
> IP preservation enabled, SSL pass-through will not work.

More information here as well: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

You can use the `real_ip` and `geo` modules to create the IP whitelist configuration. Alternatively, the [loadBalancerSourceRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#restrict-inbound-traffic-to-specific-ip-ranges) should let you whitelist any client IP ranges by updating the associated NSG.

Comment: Thanks setting the service to externalTrafficPolicy=Local did the trick!
limiting the IPs i'm doing using Nginx proxy protocol directive - this still have a problem with broken header but i'm now getting the client IPs.

Comment: I spent way too long trying to figure this one out. In my case, always in AKS, but switching between installing with the `deploy.yaml` provided in GitHub vs installing with Helm, broke it for me. Early on I set this flag to the Helm install, but it still didn't work, so I wasted a few hours trying a few other things. In the end, it was the Capitalization on the flag, which I had not considered. Thanks for posting this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Deploying my traefik ingress as part of my own helm deployment.

values.yaml

```
traefik:
  deployment:
    enabled: true
    kind: DaemonSet  # Deployment
    ingressClass:
      enabled: true
      isDefaultClass: true
  service:
    spec:
      externalTrafficPolicy: Local  # Preserve IP from LB to AKS
  logs:
    general:
      format: json
      level: INFO 
    access:
      enabled: true
      format: json
      fields:
        general:
          defaultmode: keep
        headers:
          defaultmode: keep
```

kubectl logs daemonsets/-traefik -f